# Is presure inversely related to velocity?

Tags: pressure

. [image]

I’m not sure if that picture worked or not but it’s a question from my textbook that was asking what factors would cause velocity of blood in an artery to decrease. It says in the answer at the bottom that apparently a lower pressure would
Cause this, but I thought pressure and velocity were inversely related because of Bernoulli’s law?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Bernoulli equation uses the energy of the fluid before and after traveling through different cross sectional areas. [This is a link to a good explanation of the principle.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html) In general, when a fluid's speed increases, its pressure decreases, that's why planes can fly so well, the lower pressure, faster moving air above the wing causes a net upward force called **lift**.